# How to disable BackStack with MvxFragment MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a fragment which should not be navigated back to when the Back button is pressed.

My Activity inherits from MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity

My Fragment inherits from MvxFragment and it has the AddToBackStack set to false in the MvxFragmentAttribute above the class as follows:

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.main_frame_layout, false)]
[Register("myproject.droid.fragments.MyFragment ")]
public class MyFragment : MvxFragment<MyViewModel>
{
```

However when I navigate to it and then to my next frament and press the back button then it navigates back to it even though AddToBackStack is false.

The code for the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity can be found here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.cs

It appears to do the right thing in the ShowFragment method (Line 234):

```
if ((currentFragment != null && fragInfo.AddToBackStack) || forceAddToBackStack)
{
    ft.AddToBackStack(fragInfo.Tag);
}
```

ShowFragment is not called with forceAddToBackStack set to true.

How can I prevent my fragment being added to the back stack?

Comment: Is the next fragment you navigate to set to true for the `AddToBackStack` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the fragment you are navigating to after the `First Fragment` has it's `AddToBackStack` set to `true`, you will experience this behaviour. While the `First Fragment` is not getting added to the backstage the activity that is holding it is getting added.

Therefore when you navigate to the `Second Fragment` you actual have 2 items in your backstack, the `Activity` and the `Second Fragment`. Navigating back from the `Second Fragment` will take you back to the previous shown fragment within the `Activity` which in this case is your `First Fragment`.

To solve this issue you can set `AddToBackStack` to `false` on the `Second Fragment` which would mean that it's back navigation will fall under that of the `Activity`.